# Applying Network flows

Tags: java, python, algorithm, computer-science, network-flow

So I've recently started looking into network flows (Max flow, min cuts, etc) and the general problems for network flow always involve assigning "n" of something to "k" of another thing. For example, how would I set up a network flow for "n" children in a city that has "k" schools such that the children's homes are within x kilometres of the school (for simplicity, let's just say 1km)?

What if I were to further add limitations, for example, say each school cannot have more than 100 students? Or 300 students? Could someone help me with how I would initially set up my algorithm to approach problems like these (would appreciate any references too)? They tend to show up on past midterms/exams, so I just wanted to be prepared

Comment: In general such problems (with extra constraints) can be NP-hard, so that means that then there is not much choice than to backtrack, and try all possible solutions. Only if the constraints are "structured" it is possible to solve these efficiently. When you limit the number of students, you can however add that as the capacity of the "school" to the "drain".

Comment: Ah, I see. In other words, trying to solve this in Polynomial time by structuring the constraints appropriately would be sufficient?

Comment: No, he meant: a lot of those problems, which look similar (e.g. combinations of at most / at least; or overlappings) to some *easy* problems are just hard and there is nothing to beat it's exponential worst-case for general input as long as P/NP is unresolved (and if it's resolved with !=).But of course none of those should be expected to appear in some exam which asks for a polynomial solution / network-flow solution with polynomial-size graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create vertices for each student and each school. Draw an edge with capacity 1 from each student to each school that they can attend according to your distance constraint. Create a source vertex with edges to each student with a capacity of 1. Create a sink vertex with edges coming in from each school with capacities equal to each school's maximum capacity.

Running a standard max-flow algorithm will match as many students as possible to schools. Not every student is guaranteed to get to go to school, of course, given the constraints.

This is basically a modification of the standard maximum bipartite matching algorithm. The main difference is that the sinks have capacities greater than 1, which allows multiple students to be matched to a school.